# Angular ngFor calling a function which returns an Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm using a function to return an Observable then using the async pipe in the template however this results in thousands of network requests and crashes the browser. I'm sure it's pretty obvious however I'm new to Angular. I've created an example on stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mvpknj

```
<h1>Todos</h1>
<<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let todo of completedTodos | async" >{{ todo.title }}</li>
  <!-- <li *ngFor="let todo of getCompletedTodos() | async" >{{ todo.title }}</li> -->
</ul>
```

The uncommented line works fine as it's referring to a class variable rather than a function.

If you uncomment the *ngFor which uses the getCompletedTodo function it simply blows the browser up.

Comment: This is a great example of why function expressions should be avoided in templates as Angular calls them many times, and then many times again if other properties are changing. Your approach to assign the result to a class property is vastly more efficient than a function expression. This isn’t just because of ngFor, this about Angular and change detection. Try doing the same thing with primitive data and log how much it gets called with function expressions. This is why Pipe are recommended in many situations because it can cache results.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the reason is, when the for loop iterates, for each iteration, the method `getCompletedTodo()` is executed, which calls the API and it will keep on sending requests as you can see in the browser tools and hence blows up the browser.

Comment: yap I think  @dileepkumar jami is right. getCompletedTodo() function execute again and again. I have shown in the developer's tools.

Comment: Is not because the loop iterates, it’s because of angular change detection. There are many articles as well as documents covering the mechanism as well as how to optimize rendering and performance. Basically avoiding function calls in templates helps avoid serious performance/memory issues like this.

Comment: It's got nothing to do with change detection, go and change the getCompletedTodo() method just to console.log, you will see it only logs a few times. It's to do with the Observable. I've updated it so the getCompletedTodo() functions returns the class variable rather than calling a service. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mvpknj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a little bit. You can find it in this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eptb6j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). As far as I can tell, it only executed once.

Comment: The issue happens when getCompletedTodos() returns appService.completedTodos();

Comment: I completely removed (actually, commented out) that function.

Comment: I understand what you changed however I need to be able to call a function and pass an argument to it, the code I created was just an example

Comment: I see. I trust you have a valid use case for that. But I can tell you, from experience, that using a function will cause angular to execute it numerous times. So I rarely use a function in a situation like that. One thing you could try is preventing the rendering of the markup until some variable has been set in the component, using something like *ngIf="dataIsPresent".

Comment: Ok, looking at the comments I should probably just refer to a class variable, I think if I create a couple of new components instead of trying to do it one I should be able to achieve this. Thanks